# How can I sign File Version and Product Version for DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, version

My web application is published as a precompiled mode (full site), so all my resource files (*.resx) are now replaced by some resource DLLs like this.

```
app_localresources.usercontrols.245f38a1.dll
app_localresources.usercontrols.cdcab7d2.dll
app_localresources.usercontrols8.1.cdcab7d2.dll
```

Both their File Version and Product Version are '0.0.0.0'. I need to update them to a specific number, ie. '2018.4.22'.

I am looking for a tool that can sign that information for those DLLs, but I have not found yet.

I also read SignTool from MSDN, but it does not have a parameter to do that.

Is there another tool can do it? Please advice me!

Comment: The version numbers are usually in an AssemblyInfo file.  For VB projects, this is usually accessed through the project properties; on the Application ply, there is an "Assembly Information..." button which provides access to title, description, company, version, etc.  If you want to share common info between several files, there are things you can do to make it happen, but it requires hand-editing your project file (no direct IDE support).

Comment: yes, I knew that. But the problem here is, those DLLs do not belong to my solution, and they are not AssemblyInfo file too. They are automatically generated when I publish my web app. Maybe, I can solve this issue by using compilers element in web.config file to configure a setting and tell the compiler to assign FileVersion and Product Version for the DLLs. I am not sure about that, but I am on my way to figure it out.